# Elasticsearch search always returns empty results

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I use the 7.6.1 version of Elasticsearch, I try to index simple objects and query them.
I index with no problem, I'm able to query by id, but when I try to use search with Term query it fails (0 Hit). I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
PUT product/_doc/b0264dad-6739-49ea-b691-e05a2883a724
{
  "name": "Name 2",
  "description": "Desc 1",
  "price": 11,
  "startSell": "2020-06-28T12:24:37.0070067+00:00",
  "endSell": "2020-07-19T12:24:37.0070161+00:00",
  "variants": [
    {
      "color": "Red",
      "size": 1
    },
    {
      "color": "Red",
      "size": 1
    },
    {
      "color": "Red",
      "size": 1
    },
    {
      "color": "Blue",
      "size": 1
    },
    {
      "color": "Yellow",
      "size": 1
    },
    {
      "color": "Yellow",
      "size": 2
    },
    {
      "color": "Yellow",
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "color": "Purple",
      "size": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Works and I can get the object by it's id :

```
GET product/_doc/b0264dad-6739-49ea-b691-e05a2883a724
```

Returns

```
{
  "_index" : "product",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "b0264dad-6739-49ea-b691-e05a2883a724",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 6,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "Name 2",
    "description" : "Desc 1",
    "price" : 11,
    "startSell" : "2020-06-28T12:24:37.0070067+00:00",
    "endSell" : "2020-07-19T12:24:37.0070161+00:00",
    "variants" : [
      {
        "color" : "Red",
        "size" : 1
      },
      {
        "color" : "Red",
        "size" : 1
      },
      {
        "color" : "Red",
        "size" : 1
      },
      {
        "color" : "Blue",
        "size" : 1
      },
      {
        "color" : "Yellow",
        "size" : 1
      },
      {
        "color" : "Yellow",
        "size" : 2
      },
      {
        "color" : "Yellow",
        "size" : 3
      },
      {
        "color" : "Purple",
        "size" : 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But all the three requests return **no data**, what am I doing wrong ? :

```
POST product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "name": [
              "Name 2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


POST product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": {
        "value": "Name 2",
        "boost": 1
      }
    }
  }
}

POST product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "description": {
        "value": "Desc 1",
        "boost": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the mapping of your index?

Comment: How could I find this in Kibana ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly its due to the fact that these fields `name` and `description` is defined as a `text` field in your index which uses the `standard analyzer` by default and split on the whitespace so tokens generated for these fields would be `name` and `2` for your `name` field and `desc` and `1` for  `description` field.

while you are using the `term` query which is not analyzed and tried to match the `name 2` token which doesn't exist.

**Solution:** Change the query to `match` query, otherwise use the `.keyword` field if mapping is generated automatically or define a keyword field to store the data if you intend to use the `term` query.

Refer [difference b/w term vs match query with example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60867368/4039431)

Comment: I ended up with the same conclusion, Kibana provides me the intellisense about the .keyword syntax, thank you for the useful link too!