# Elastic search query not returning results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, term-query

I have an Elastic Search query that is not returning data. Here are 2 examples of the query - the first one works and returns a few records but the second one returns nothing - what am I missing?

Example 1 works:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "data.case.field1": "ABC123"
    }
  }
}
'
```

Example 2 not working:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term" : { "data.case.field1" : "ABC123" }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is happening due to the difference between `match` and `term` queries, `match` queries are **analyzed**, which means it applied the same analyzer on the search term, which is used on field at index time, while `term` queries are not analyzed, and used for exact searches, and `search term` in term queries doesn't go through the [analysis process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html).

Official doc of [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

> Returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.

Official doc of [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

> Returns documents that match a provided text, number, date or boolean
> value. **The provided text is analyzed before matching.**

If you are using text field for `data.case.field1` without any explicit analyzer than the default analyzer(standard) for the text field would be applied, which lowercase the text and store the resultant token.

For your text, a standard analyzer would produce the below token, please refer [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) for more details.

```
{
    "text" : "ABC123",
    "analyzer" : "standard"
}
```

**And generated token**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "abc123",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

**Now, when you use `term` query as a search term will not be analyzed and used as it is, which is in captical char(ABC123) it doesn't match the tokens in the index, hence doesn't return result.**

PS: refer my [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60867368/4039431) for more details on term and match queries.

Answer (score 1):

What is your mapping for `data.case.field1`? If it is of type **text**, you should use a **match** query instead of **term**.

See the warning at the top of this page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query

Answer (score 0):

Unless we know the mapping type as `text` or `keyword`. It is relatively answering in the dark without knowing all the variables involved. May be you can try the following.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": { <- Try this if you have datatype as keyword
        "term" : { "data.case.field1" : "ABC123" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

'