# How can I write "select * from users where username ='kuldeep' and (status = 'active' OR status = 'inactive' )" in elastic with exact search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I tried this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match" : { "username": "kuldeep" }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : {"status": "inactive"} },
        { "term" : { "status": "active" } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting results using the above query, but it returns users with the username kuldeep and kuldeep singh.

```
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 8.914892,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "searchusers",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "6f9b37b1-2934-4125-bbf9-875e61c60730",
                "_score": 8.914892,
                "_source": {
                    "status": "active",
                    "createdOn": 1637145140000,
                    "id": "6f9b37b1-2934-4125-bbf9-875e61c60730",
                    "agreementAccepted": false,
                    "userNumber": "0000000000001251",
                    "email": "",
                    "createdBy": "a91a9b69-7774-4e2e-8901-037045c4f5e0",
                    "username": "kuldeep"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "searchusers",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1744d7ae-3454-4ad4-9ea9-591102eb0369",
                "_score": 6.8384924,
                "_source": {
                    "status": "active",
                    "createdOn": 1639458287000,
                    "id": "1744d7ae-3454-4ad4-9ea9-591102eb0369",
                    "agreementAccepted": false,
                    "userNumber": "0000000000002429",
                    "email": "",
                    "createdBy": "39057c58-3ed6-457d-a832-2f69a2472943",
                    "username": "kuldeep singh"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As mentioned in elastic docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) minimum_should_match default value is 0 if it includes match or filter. When I changed minimum_should_match to 1 it returns no data.

```
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Also when using minimum_should_match as 0 it seems the should query has no impact in result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For exact search instead of `match` you need to use the `term` query, also you need to use the `term` query on the keyword field not on the `text` field, so if you are using the default mapping of Elasticsearch, for every `text` field there is `.keyword` field, in this case you can simply change relevant part of your query to below:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : {
            "username.keyword" : "kuldeep"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, by using the `.keyword` is working, I have to use the `.keyword` in the should query also. 

Here is the complete query. 

` {
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "username.keyword": "kuldeep" }
      },
      "should" : [
         { "term" : {"status.keyword": "inactive"} },
         { "term" : { "status.keyword": "active" } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: @KuldeepRana yes you need to use that in all the place where you want to do the exact search and it makes sense in case of `status` field as well, you can take a look at my this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60867368/4039431 to understand the diff better