# how do we use and query the keyword field?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I do

```
PUT /vehicles/_doc/123
{
  "make" : "Honda Civic", 
  "color" : "Blue", 
  "from": "Japan",
  "size": "Big",
  "comment": "deja vu",
  "HP" : 250, 
  "milage" : 24000, 
  "price": 19300.97
}
```

It automatically generate the index definition below:

```
{
  "vehicles": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "HP": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "color": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "comment": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "from": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "make": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "milage": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "size": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "vehicles",
        "creation_date": "1670864230815",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "etLFicsvSXCpeuFiYCiT0g",
        "version": {
          "created": "8050299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the index, say `color`, it has type `text`, and there is a field `keyword`, how do we use and query the `keyword` field?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `color.keyword` in your query when you want to query the keyword field, if you want to just query the `text` part, you simply use the `color` in field name.

`text` and `keyword` fields are tokenised and stored differently and used in different scenario, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60867368/4039431) will be useful for understand the difference.